# Does these rational sequences always reach an integer?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions, computational-number-theory

Let $u_0 \ge 2$ be a rational, and $u_{n+1}=⌊u_n⌋(u_n - ⌊u_n⌋ + 1)$.
**Question**: Does the sequence $(u_n)$ reach an integer?

It was checked by computer (with SageMath) for $u_0=\frac{p}{q}$ with $p \le 32000$.
*Example*: if $u_0=\frac{11}{5}$ then $(u_n)= (\frac{11}{5}, \frac{12}{5}, \frac{14}{5}, \frac{18}{5}, \frac{24}{5}, \frac{36}{5}, \frac{42}{5}, \frac{56}{5}, \frac{66}{5}, \frac{78}{5}, 24, \dots)$.

A positive answer would provide an alternative to [continued fraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) theory (see cross-post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/377925/34538)).

Comment: $⌊x⌋$ is the floor of $x$.

Comment: Based on your sage program, how many iterations would it take to reach an integer?

Comment: @SeanNemetz: it depends on the rational number one starts with. For example, with $u_0 = \frac{10307}{4513}$, it requires $58254$ iterations to reach an integer. Based on Sage computation, with $u_0=\frac{p}{q}$, it seems to require at most *about* $kq \log(q)$ iterations, where $k>0$ is a constant.